# does jquery.html() have a "ready" or "complete" callback?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm using DOM insertion to generate some data entry dialogs. I'm finding that in some browsers, particularly mobile browsers and IE-Mac, manipulations immediately after the `.html()` call don't fire, presumably because the modified DOM is not yet ready. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#theDialog").html(data);

        // hide address
        $("#theDialog #BillingAddress").closest("li").hide();
        ...
```

This works most of the time, but certain browsers *sometimes* fail to hide the indicated `<li>`. And it's been challenging to debug, because going to console seems to allow the browser to complete the DOM insertion, and so the `.hide()` *always* works when stepping through the code.

I suppose what I'm after is either a `$("#theDialog").on("ready")` or a callback from the `.html()` method. But those don't seem to exist.

I've thought of

1. Switching to `.load()`, but eventually I'll be converting to JSONP and I don't think `.load()` supports that?
2. Putting the `.hide()` and other DOM manipulation in a script tag within the returned data.

I suspect #2 is the recommended approach but wanted to do a sanity check here first. Has anyone experienced this?

Many thanks.

Comment: requestCallback.requestComplete(true);

Comment: IE-mac?  omg... please tell me nobody still uses IE on mac.  PLEASE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although my previous answer worked, it didn't solve all your problems.  I recommend something like:

```
var myDiv=document.createElement( 'div' );
myDiv.innerHTML=data;
// now do all of your initializing, passing in myDiv like $( myDiv )
$("#theDialog").html(myDiv.innerHTML)
  .find( '#BillingAddress' )
  .closest("li")
  .hide();
```

Hope this works!

Comment: I believe it does, though it's decidedly hard to test because I can't make the error reoccur reliably.

Comment: I used this to adjust css, instead of .closest using .css() and was able to chain .css() calls also!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$("#theDialog").html(data);
// hide address
$("#theDialog #BillingAddress").closest("li").hide();
```

Have you tried:

```
$("#theDialog").html(data).find( '#BillingAddress' ).closest("li").hide();
```

I haven't experienced this myself, but hopefully this works!

Comment: That seems to work but I'm doing quite a lot of manipulation at that stage. The biggest thing is initializing the `<div>` into a jQueryUI dialog, and that also doesn't always work -- the dialog button action events don't get hooked, `.button()` calls don't fire, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It does not have a callback function but you can use `.promise()` and `.done()`

```
$('#selector').html(someText).promise().done(function(){
        //callback code
    });
```

Comment: The [promise function](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) is not linked to the html ready event but to the animation.